# Does silverlight's pivot viewer support html descriptions?

Tags: silverlight, pivotviewer

I'm building a silverlight pivot viewer collection which contains html descriptions; however the html markup is showing up in the description.

Does silverlight's pivot viewer support html descriptions? If so please reference a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PivotViewer does not support HTML out of the box.  Depending on your the version you are running there are solutions to resolve this, by creating a custom detail pane.

If you are using the v1 PivotViewer there is no API for customizing the detail pane.  However, if you take a look at [PivotViewer Lessons](http://pivotviewerlessons.codeplex.com) you find an example of how to replace the detail pane.

In the SL5 version, it's much easier to replace the detail pane.  I have a blog post on doing that here on my blog : [SL5 PivotViewer Custom Detail Pane](http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2011/10/sl5-pivotviewer-custom-detailpanestyle/)

Then you can add a control to in your detail pane to parse out the HTML.